# Grafana Loki escape character

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, fluent-plugin-grafana-loki

I send docker logs from fluent bit to grafana
tcpdump shows that fluent bit send log with escape character:
i need to escape double quotes by \

**example of tcpdump output:**

`[["1701677792000000000","message=\"Query error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: \"713dsa\"\nLINE 4: AND \"curs_id\" = '713dsa'\n                        ^ - Invalid query: SELECT *\nFROM \"courses\"\nWHERE \"archive\" = 0\nAND \"curs_id\" = '713dsa'\" level_name=\"ERROR\" channel=\"production\" datetime=\"2023-12-04 11:16:32\" server_name=\"_\" host_name=\"main-ry.com\""],["1701677792000000000","message=\"Uncaught Exception Error: \"Call to a member function row_array() on bool\" at /var/www/html/application/models/Teacher_model.php line 1722\" level_name=\"ERROR\" channel=\"production\" datetime=\"2023-12-04 11:16:32\" server_name=\"_\" host_name=\"main-ry.com\""]]}]}`

**but in loki i see that data comes without escaping double quotes and not in a one string:**

`message=“Query error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: “713dsa” LINE 4: AND “curs_id” = ‘713dsa’ ^ - Invalid query: SELECT * FROM “courses” WHERE “archive” = 0 AND “curs_id” = ‘713dsa’” level_name=“ERROR” channel=“production” datetime=“2023-12-04 11:16:32” server_name=“" host_name=“main-ry.com"�message=“Uncaught Exception Error: “Call to a member function row_array() on bool” at /var/www/html/application/models/Teacher_model.php line 1722” level_name=“ERROR” channel=“production” datetime=“2023-12-04 11:16:32” server_name=”” host_name=“main-ry.com”`

do someone know a reason?
or maybe someone saw similar problem?